# What does this statement mean in linear algebra :$Ker(M) = \mathbb{F_p}$ for $p$ a prime

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the last followup question to my other question. Here I have a matrix $M$ whose kernel is the field $\mathbb{F_p}$. I'm not sure what this expression is saying or why it is important. My understanding is that $\mathbb{F_p}$ is a field that contains individual non-vector elements so how can this possibly be in the kernel of matrix $M$?

For example, let us say that I have this matrix in $\mathbb{F_3}$ when is that matrix's kernel $\mathbb{F_3}$ ?

Comment: To reiterate the previous comment, $\Bbb{F}_3$ is the 1-dimensional vector space over itself. Any matrix over a field $K$ has $K$ for its kernel whenever it has a $1$-dimensional kernel.

Comment: @DevenWare Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

(Comment converted to answer by request)

The key idea is that elements in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ can be thought of as both scalars and *one dimensional* vectors.

So lets go through your example in detail. You have a matrix $\mathrm{M}$ in $\mathrm{Mat}_{n\times m}(\mathbb{F}_3)$. That means as map,

$M : \mathbb{F}_3^m \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_3^n$

So, $\mathrm{Ker(M)} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_3^m$. When we say that $\mathrm{Ker(M)} = \mathbb{F}_3$ what we are doing is actually abusing notation (in a very convenient way.) We actually mean that its kernel is a one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_3^m$.